Flutter camera_web setFlashMode returns TypeError on Android Google Chrome
Im making a web-app that needs to enable torch/flash using Flutter. However, whenever I try to enable flash, I get an error:
Type Error: true: type 'bool' is not a subtype of type 'JSArray<Object?>?'
I've tested this on both Samsung Galaxy S21 and Google Pixel 6 Pro with Google Chrome for Android. Same error on both devices.
The preview works fine, and I've also tested recording, which works, but not setFlashMode(FlashMode.always), which throws the same error.
Here is my code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CameraScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const CameraScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<CameraScreen> createState() => _CameraScreenState();
}

class _CameraScreenState extends State<CameraScreen> {
  late CameraController controller;
  bool isInitialised = false;

  Future<void> initialiseCamera() async {
    final cameras = await availableCameras();
    controller = CameraController(cameras.last, ResolutionPreset.max, enableAudio: false);
    if (!mounted) return;
    try {
      await controller.initialize();
      setState(() {
        isInitialised = true;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      if (e is CameraException) {
        switch (e.code) {
          case 'CameraAccessDenied':
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  void enableFlash() {
    if (isInitialised) {
          controller.setFlashMode(FlashMode.always);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    initialiseCamera();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Builder(builder: (context) {
              if (!isInitialised) {
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
              return AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 9 / 16, child: CameraPreview(controller));
            }),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: enableFlash,
                child: const Text("Flash"),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


